# C program works on my Ubuntu VM terminal but not on school Linux server?

Tags: c++, c, linux, linux-kernel

I have this C program that runs perfectly on my Ubuntu Virtual Machine but does not run at all(doesn't prompt user for input, just finishes) on the school Linux server.

School Linux version: Linux 2.6.18-371.9.1.e15 x86_64

My Ubuntu VM version: Linux 3.16.0-33-generic x86_64

Here is the program:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 int main()
 {
    char value[50];
    char *end;
    int sum = 0;
    long conv;
    while(conv != 0 )
    {
            printf("Enter a measurement and unit(Ex: 4' or 3\";0' or 0\" when done): ");
            fgets(value, 50, stdin);
            conv = strtol(value, &end, 10);
            if(strstr(value, "\'") != NULL)
            {
                    conv = strtol(value, &end, 10);
                    sum = sum + (conv*12);
            }
            else if(strstr(value, "\"") != NULL)
            {
                    conv = strtol(value, &end, 10);
                    sum = sum + conv;
            }
    }
    printf("Total: %d, %s\n", sum, "inches" );
    return 0;
 }
```

Any idea why this is??

P.S. thanks to those who helped me with this program from an earlier question :)

Comment: suggest compiling with all warnings enabled.  (-Wall -Wextra -pedantic) then the compiler would have told you about using an uninitialized variable (cond).   This is an example of a good reason to initialize all local variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initially set `conv`, for example:

```
long conv = ~0;
```

As far as it running perfectly on one machine and not at all on another, you just got lucky.  `conv` does have a value, even if you don't explicitly set it.  On one machine, it was `0` and on the other it was something other than `0`, hence the different behavior.

Another method would be to use a `do while` loop:

```
do
{
    ...
}
while(conv != 0);
```

Comment: I chose your answer because of the extra explanation. I also liked the do{}while better than setting the long conv to a nonzero number. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The value of conv is undefined by your program, so the "while" loop exits immediately. Try setting it to some nonzero value.